# Creating a React project in Visual Studio 2022 is not working, error on installing react react-dom react-scripts with cra-template

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio

here is an image after a failed attempt at creating the react project on visual studio

[image]

I saved the log data, but how to upload it?

update : I reset my firewall and reinstalled nodejs and nothing change, it just either gets stuck or there is an error

Comment: Are you working from an office where there might be a proxy or firewall? Have you tried connecting to a different internet connection to see if it works that way?

Comment: I am working from a private dorm however i doubt that is the case. i switched to Mobile data and im trying it as we speak. i will let you know the verdict
| edit: it worked thank you so much :)

Comment: Awesome! I posted an answer with that solution. Please mark it as the answer since it did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely your internet connection blocking the connection for some reason. Trying another internet connection will eliminate that as a possibility.